# .net Core 3.1 Linq Expression "...could not be translated." Exception

Tags: linq, asp.net-core

```
var asd = (from a in _context.Nodes
           where (Convert.ToDateTime(a.NodeProcessTime).Date >= DateTime.Now.Date.AddMonths(-5) && Convert.ToDateTime(a.NodeProcessTime).Date <= DateTime.Now.Date.AddMonths(-4))
           select a).Count();
```

I am trying to get the count of the records between two dates. But an exception appears below. NodeProcessTime is a string. Needs to be converted to dateTime. Am I missing something?

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression 'Where(
> source: DbSet,
> predicate: (n) => ToDateTime(n.NodeProcessTime).Date >= DateTime.Now.Date.AddMonths(-5) && ToDateTime(n.NodeProcessTime).Date
> <= DateTime.Now.Date.AddMonths(-4))' could not be translated. Either
> rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to
> client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either
> AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().

Comment: As far as I know, it's a breaking change. Going forward it's not possible to use things that cannot be translated to SQL such as this date manipulations. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.x/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client)

Comment: I tried them all but they are not working. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```cs
// Convert (I asumme) string to date 
Date ToDate(string dateTime) => Convert.ToDateTime(dateTime).Date;

// Offset current datetime
Date OffsetNow(int offset) => DateTime.Now.Date.AddMonths(offset);

// Check date is between range
bool IsBetween(Date d) => ToDate(d) >= OffsetNow(-5) && ToDate(d) <= OffsetNow(-4);


var asd = _context.Nodes.Count(n => IsBetween(n));
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use sqlFunction to translate it.

```
SqlFunctions.DateAdd("day", 0 ,  a.NodeProcessTime)
```

just add zero day to your string column

Answer (score 0):

```
            List<DateTime> dateTimes = new List<DateTime>();
           
            foreach (var item in _context.Nodes.ToList())
            {
                dateTimes.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(item.NodeScanDateTime.Substring(0, 10)));
            };
            int counts = dateTimes.Where(a => a > DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-5)& a < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-4)).Count();
```

Now at first I get the string NodeScanDateTime for all nodes and put them to a list. After that I cut them like "10.05.2020" type by using substring and convert them to DateTime. Then I made my query and now it works. Thanks for all...